# Calling a C program from the function in pthread_create

Tags: c, pthreads, job-scheduling

We are trying to implement a Process scheduling code for Round Robin process as part of our project.

As part of trying to implement the code,we need to processes which we then need to schedule according to Round-Robin.

The processes we are taking in our case are 3 separate independent C programs.So where I am stuck is that when I call pthread_create( , , func, ). 
I want this 'func' parameter to call my C program and execute it.How can I call my three separate C programs in my original C program using pthreads.

Also if someone could direct me to some resources/links where I could understand how to go about this better. I understand Round Robin perfectly.

Comment: Can someone help me here?

Answer (score 1):

For your task you shouldn't use threads. `fork` is the right tool to create independent processes.

Comment: ...followed by `execve` (or a related function) in the child process to execute the program.

Comment: We have been specifically asked to use 3-4 threads which will call their own indpendent C programs (like FFT Calculator, Matrix Multiplication) which we have to schedule using Round Robin.

Comment: You can call e. g. `execve()` from the different threads to satisfy the silly asking, even if that's an unnecessary complication.